# Converter for VB.NET Code to Linux Platform Exist?

Tags: vb.net, linux, ms-access

I am interested in moving a number of my projects from Visual Studio and Access/Office Basic with a SQL back-end to the Linux world.

Are there any utilities available to move code over to a similar platform on Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to the [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to get started.  It will help you pinpoint Microsoft specific calls, but you'll probably have to do the db conversion and data access layer manually.  You may be surprised - mono does have a System.Data.SqlClient namespace so you may not have much work to do.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenOffice](http://openoffice.org) has a [Basic](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide) interpreter which is largely compatible with VBA. This may help you with your Access applications. The OpenOffice versions should run on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There are some flavours of OpenOffice that include native support for VBA. The version included with Ubuntu is one example, and the [Novell version for Windows](http://www.novell.com/products/openworkgroupsuite/product_evals.html) is another. For more details and a list of versions with this feature, see [this article on linux.com](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/58348).

They don't support all features of VBA, but they will reduce your conversion effort.